# Why does high leverage point in SLR have unusual covariate values

Tags: regression, terminology, leverage

As stated above and also wondering what a covariate value means, is it just covariance? IF not, then what it is and what is the difference between covariance and covariate

Answer (score 0):

A *covariate* means the same as predictor, input variable or the old term independent variable. So it is not the same thing as covariance! And then the Q in the title

> Why does high leverage point in SLR have unusual covariate values?

Leverage means influence, so a high leverage point is a point with high influence on the fitted regression model. You can find details at [Leverages and effect of leverage points](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/212656/leverages-and-effect-of-leverage-points).  In short, a high leverage point is an outlier in $X$-space.